# get all main results even when one row is missing

Tags: php, mysql

I have a small database : table **invoices** contains the invoices for every sale, table **detail** contains the detail lines for every sale, each invoice should have one or more detail lines :

[image]

In previous image, table **invoices** contains 3 sales with ids **1**, **2** and **3**. Table **detail** contains detail lines for invoices **1** and **3** only because someone accidentally deleted the detail line for invoice **2**.

Now I have to create a report that shows **all** invoices and their ticket types. I tried next query but the invoice **2** is missing because it doesn't have detail lines :

```
SELECT invoices.id,
       detail.ticket_type
  FROM invoices
  JOIN detail
    ON detail.invoice = invoices.id
```

The result is :

```
 id            ticket_type
───────────────────────────
 1             adult
 1             child
 3             hot dog
```

I have tried variations with the same result, like :

```
SELECT invoices.id,
       detail.ticket_type
  FROM detail
  JOIN ( SELECT id
           FROM invoices
       ) AS invoices
    ON detail.invoice = invoices.id
```

So, my question is : how can I get **all** the invoices' ids and their ticket types when some invoices don't have detail lines? In those cases the **ticket_type** column must remain blank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT invoices.id,
       coalesce(detail.ticket_type, '') ticket_type
  FROM invoices
  LEFT JOIN detail
    ON detail.invoice = invoices.id
```

please notice the swapped `invoices` and `detail`. use the table from which you want all rows in the `FROM` clause, use `LEFT JOIN` to add detail.